# How to retain position of Sub Menu on Hover

Tags: css

I am having trouble retaining a sub menu's position when hovering.

http://bit.ly/1IgmNKT

When you hover over "Services", a sub menu pulldown appears as it should. Then as you slowly hover down over top of the sub menu, once you reach the sub menu its position shifts up.

What am I missing in my css to have the sub menu retain its position and not shift up?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the selector at line 61 of your custom-styles.css, make the 39px bottom padding permanent, like so:

```
ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item a {
    color: #7a828d;
    padding: 0 24px 39px;
}
```

You can then remove the padding-bottom from your a:hover.

Comment: No probs! Note that if your green bar is supposed to overlay the dark blue bar below your header exactly, then at the moment it's appearing a couple of pixels too high for me (in FF 38 I should add).

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
 ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item a:hover, ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item a:active {
padding-bottom: 39px;
}
```

from your css, because the a:hover of the menu item is pushing the padding down 39px

Comment: But that's the desired starting effect @nolawipetros -- to get the lime green bar to slide across the upper portion of the body page. It works the same on About and Contact except those two verticals do not have sub menus.